# How do I get into advanced options for the Surface 2 (Windows RT 8.1)

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface, windows-rt, recovery

Heyo, Super User, I've been looking for the answer to this on Google, all of em say you need to get into windows. One issue. winload.efi is corrupted or missing, so my Surface is in recovery. idk why, but it is. I just need to use cmd to use chkdsk. Here's a video if it helps:
 https://parappawithfries.com/surface

Comment: chkdsk is very unlikely to fix your problem since it won’t restore the missing file

Comment: but, its not missing. its corrupted.

Comment: this has happened multiple times, i just cant remember what to do to get to cmd

Comment: chkdsk, can only do so much, it doesn’t repair corrupted files.  In order to get a command prompt within the Windows recovery environment (WinRE) you must have a working recovery partition which doesn’t appear to be the case

Comment: ... WinRE uses a seperate efi file, located in C:\Windows\Boot (for Windows RT 8.1).. I just don't know how to get it to boot to it (AKA advanced options).

Comment: I've been through corrupted boot files, and chkdsk fixed em...